# My while-loop will not repeat itself in C program

Tags: c, while-loop

My code is for school and is designed to store speeds of cars entered by users and then find the average speeds of non-speeders & speeders (anything over 65 is speeding). My problem is, every time I run this, it only allows me to enter one speed and then it shows the average which is just the speed itself. I'm looking for it to keep repeating and storing the values until '-1' is entered which should end the loop. Can anyone check out my code and please help.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
void main(void)
{
int count1 = 0;
int count2 = 0;
double speed;
double speeders = 0;
double legals = 0;
double average1;
double average2;
int finished = 0;

while (finished != 1)
{
  printf("Enter a speed (or -1 to quit):\n");
  scanf("%lf", &speed);

  if (speed > 65)
 {
  printf("SPEEDING\n");
  speeders = speeders + speed;
  count1++;
  }
  else if (speed >= 0 && speed <= 65)
  {
  printf("OK\n");
  legals = legals + speed;
  count2++;
  }
  else (speed == -1)
 ;{
  finished = 1;
  }

}
  average1 = speeders / (double)count1;
  average2 = legals / (double)count2;
  printf("The average speed of the speeders is: %lf, and the average     speed of the non-speeders is: %lf\n", average1, average2);
}
```

Comment: Your choice of [indenting style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style) for this code (and inconsistent use of that style) contributed to making the problem with this code not as clear as it might be. Indenting styles exist to make programmer's jobs easier. It makes spotting issues like this significantly more faster/easier/clearer. I *strongly* suggest that you get in the habit of consistently using an indenting style. In the programming you do, you will likely end up using multiple different styles, depending on the project, but any project should pick one style and use it consistently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code block here:

```
else (speed == -1)
;{
finished = 1;
}
```

Always sets `finished` to 1. You want either:

```
else if(speed == -1)
{
    finished = 1;
}
```

or simply:

```
else
{
    finished = 1;
}
```

Comment: The `;` after `else` is an empty statement (and thus is treated as a single statement `else`). I'm surprised the `(speed == -1)` after it even compiles

Comment: "else speed = -1;" compiles. "else speed == -1;" compiles but doesn't modify speed. "else (speed == -1);" compiles just as well. The else branch is a statement expression, unusually formatted, with a useless expression without side effects.

Answer (score 2):

You wrote:

```
 else (speed == -1)
;{
 finished = 1;
 }
```

Note the errant semicolon, and the attempt to put a condition on an `else`!

That's the same as this:

```
else (speed == -1);
{
finished = 1;
}
```

…or this:

```
else
{
   (speed == -1);
}
{
   finished = 1;
}
```

…or this:

```
else
{
   speed == -1;
}
{
   finished = 1;
}
```

…or this:

```
else
{
   speed == -1;
}
finished = 1;
```

…or this:

```
else
{}
finished = 1;
```

…or this:

```
finished = 1;
```

In other words, `finished` is *always* set to `1` and your `else` condition doesn't do anything.

Double check your syntax and read your code more closely!